# C: How can I print out individual digits of an integer number with a plus sign in the middle?

Tags: c

Example Of Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int n); //Prototype

int main(void){
    int number;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("%d = %d\n", number, sum(number));
}

//Sum Function
int sum(int n){
    int total = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        total += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return total;
}
```

How do I print the below sentence taking into account that the number can be dynamically chosen by the user using a scanf function and I already have a dynamic function that calculates the sum of each digit.

```
Current Output: "12345 = 15"
Desired Output: "1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15"
```

Edit: Hi all! I have updated my question to include my original code to make it clearer what I was trying to achieve. Thank you guys so much for your help!

Comment: If the input is read by scanf and converted from a string to an integer, the easiest thing to do is skip that conversion.  Instead of using `%d` in the scanf to do a conversion that you do not want, just use `%s` and keep the data as a string.  Then insert the `+` as you print it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply recursion can be used to print the first digits when the value is 10 or more, along with the `" + "`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Print each digit with a trailing " + "
static int sum_helper(int x) {
  int sum = 0;
  if (x >= 10) {
    sum += sum_helper(x / 10);
    x %= 10;
  }
  printf("%d + ", x);
  return sum + x;
}

void sum_line(int x) {
  printf("%11d: ", x);
  int last_digit = abs(x % 10);
  int sum = last_digit;
  int first_digits = abs(x / 10);
  if (first_digits) {
    sum += sum_helper(first_digits);
  }
  printf("%d = %d\n", last_digit, sum);
}
```

Test code

```
void sum_line(int x);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  sum_line(123);
  sum_line(12345);
  sum_line(0);
  sum_line(1);
  sum_line(-12345);
  sum_line(INT_MAX);
  sum_line(INT_MIN);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
        123: 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
      12345: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
          0: 0 = 0
          1: 1 = 1
     -12345: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
 2147483647: 2 + 1 + 4 + 7 + 4 + 8 + 3 + 6 + 4 + 7 = 46
-2147483648: 2 + 1 + 4 + 7 + 4 + 8 + 3 + 6 + 4 + 8 = 47
```

Comment: Crafty, but poor `sum_line()` isn't going to be much use without his friend `sum_helper()` helper, so why the use of `static` for one but not the other?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `sum_line()` is a public/global function - good for all `int`.  `sum_helper()` is a private one.  `sum_helper()` needs to be called with values > 0 and not meant for public use.

Comment: Mystery solved. I understood the effect, just not the choice in the example. But I can see how `sum_line()` makes sense as a normal function to be exposed to whoever needs it, while the helper would likely only be used in this one-off circumstance. Maybe `void sum_line(int x, int (*helper)(int))`, and `sum += helper(first_digits);`, and `sum_line(12345, sum_helper);`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73374380/c-how-can-i-print-out-individual-digits-of-an-integer-number-with-a-plus-sign-i/73375775?noredirect=1#comment129592751_73375775) would oblige the caller of `sum_line()` to see/know of  `sum_helper()`, something I am trying to not expose to the public.

Comment: Quite true. That make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is coming in as a string, the easiest thing to do is to leave it as a string.  Don't ever convert it to an `int`.  (eg, if you are reading the data with `scanf` using `%d`, just use `%s` instead).  If the data is already an integer, the easiest thing to do is (probably) to convert it to a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int number = 12345;
    char buf[128];
    int sum = 0;
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", number);
    for( char *s = buf; *s; s++ ){
        if( s != buf ){
            fputs(" + ", stdout);
        }
        putchar(*s);
        sum += *s - '0';
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest by far (and probably fastest too actually) is to stick with strings. Here's an example, error handling yet to be implemented:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[128];
  scanf("%s", str);

  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    sum += str[i] - '0'; // convert to integer digit, then add to sum

    printf("%c ", str[i]);
    if( str[i+1] == '\0' )
      printf("= ");
    else
      printf("+ ");
  }

  printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `scanf("%s", str);` --> `scanf("%127s", str);` and perhaps `char str[128] = { '\0' };`

Comment: @SupportUkraine Nah use `fgets`. But this isn't production-quality code; as I wrote, error handling has yet to be implemented.

Comment: Agree. `fgets` is to be prefered over `scanf` However, **if** `scanf("%s...` is used there should be a "maximum field width". Without it one could just as well use `gets`

Comment: With `%s` being such a common source of error, it is dangerous to post code using it.  I am nervous merely to use the string `%s` in a comment without a width modifier.  In scanf, it should always be `%Ns`.  Always.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, a [nervous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73374380/c-how-can-i-print-out-individual-digits-of-an-integer-number-with-a-plus-sign-i/73375775#comment129579000_73374380)?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Actually, the whole disaster library known as stdio.h is the common source of error and it should be avoided entirely in professional programs. Debating `%Ns` vs `%s` is like saying "I want the nitroglycerine shaken not stirred". It's gonna blow up beyond your control no matter. If you don't want your program to blow up, then don't fill it up with nitroglycerine (stdio.h).

Comment: Either way, these things aren't relevant for beginners to focus on. Nobody in their right mind writes production-quality console programs taking input from stdin in the year 2022 anyhow... for those rare cases when you need a console program, you'd use command-line arguments as input and then sanitize those before use.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, exactly.  As I was writing that, I pondered whether I should write "%Ns", but decided that would require an explanation.  It really is easiest to just post a link explaining why no one in their right mind should ever use `scanf`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient but it's a charmingly recursive solution.

The challenge isn't totally digits. The challenge is outputting them in decreasing order of significance unless you're always provided with the number as a character string!

Expected Output:

```
0 -> 0 = 0
1 -> 1 = 1
-1 -> 1 = 1
5 -> 5 = 5
15 -> 1 + 5 = 6
12345 -> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
123456 -> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21
49 -> 4 + 9 = 13
-78 -> 7 + 8 = 15
9 -> 9 = 9
-9 -> 9 = 9
10 -> 1 + 0 = 1
-10 -> 1 + 0 = 1
-2147483648 -> 2 + 1 + 4 + 7 + 4 + 8 + 3 + 6 + 4 + 8 = 47
2147483647 -> 2 + 1 + 4 + 7 + 4 + 8 + 3 + 6 + 4 + 7 = 46
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int sum(int n){
    int r=0;
    if(n>=10 || n<=-10){
        r=sum(n/10);
        printf(" + ");
    }
    int d=n%10;
    if(d<0){
        d=-d;
    }
    r+=d;
    printf("%d",d);
    return r;
}

void show(int n){
    printf("%d -> ",n);
    int r=sum(n);
    printf(" = %d\n",r);
}

int main() {
    show(0);
    show(1);
    show(-1);
    show(5);
    show(15);
    show(12345);
    show(123456);
    show(49);
    show(-78);
    show(9);
    show(-9);
    show(10);
    show(-10);
    show(INT_MIN);
    show(INT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add another solution using POSIX `div` (added to C99), that is essentially a divide and mod in a single operation using an anonymous struct. To handle conversion of an integer to an addition expression of each digit (considered a positive digit regardless of the initial sign of the integer) and allowing for definition of separator string (`SEP` below) to place between each digit, you could do something like the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXDIGIT  32            /* max number of digits */
#define SEP     " + "           /* separator */
#define SLEN sizeof(SEP) - 1    /* separator length */

void itosexpr (int n)
{
  char  buf[MAXDIGIT * SLEN] = "",          /* buffer to hold digits + sep */
        *p = buf + MAXDIGIT * SLEN - 1;     /* pointer to end of buffer */
  div_t d = { .quot = n };                  /* quotient/remainder type */
  long sum = 0;
  
  do {
    d = div (d.quot, 10);                   /* compute quotient/remainder */
    sum += abs(d.rem);                      /* add remainder to sum */
    *--p = abs(d.rem) + '0';                /* decrement & add char to buf */
    for (int i = 0; d.quot && SEP[i]; i++)  /* add sep to buf */
      *--p = SEP[i];
  } while (d.quot);                         /* test quotient non-zero */
  
  printf ("% 11d: %s = %ld\n", n, p, sum);  /* output expression & sum */
}

int main (void) {
  
  int number = 12345;
  itosexpr (number);
  itosexpr (0);
  itosexpr (1);
  itosexpr (INT_MAX);
  itosexpr (INT_MIN);
}
```

Note, this method isn't any superior or worse than any of the others, it's just another option and exposure to the `div` set of functions (with `ldiv` and `lldiv` for `long` and `long long` respectively)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/number_to_add_expr
      12345: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
          0: 0 = 0
          1: 1 = 1
 2147483647: 2 + 1 + 4 + 7 + 4 + 8 + 3 + 6 + 4 + 7 = 46
-2147483648: 2 + 1 + 4 + 7 + 4 + 8 + 3 + 6 + 4 + 8 = 47
```

If you `#define SEP "+"`, then you would have:

```
$ ./bin/number_to_add_expr2
      12345: 1+2+3+4+5 = 15
          0: 0 = 0
          1: 1 = 1
 2147483647: 2+1+4+7+4+8+3+6+4+7 = 46
-2147483648: 2+1+4+7+4+8+3+6+4+8 = 47
```

(**note:** `SEP` must be defined and must be at least a string of one valid character)

Comment: `char buf[MAXDIGIT * SLEN]` mis-sized.  Perhaps `char buf[MAXDIGIT * (SLEN+1) + 1]`? Side benefit: "SEP must be defined and must be at least a string of one valid character" --> `#define SEP     ""` works fine.

Comment: "using an anonymous struct." is it not the name `div_t`?

Comment: Given the one print (and with buffer fix), likely fastest solution.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - thank you for the feedback. Sorry late reply but had to do a round trip to Austin to move daughter into new apartment for next semester. 466 mi round trip with much furniture moved on brisk 100 deg August day -- I'm too old tor this ... I'm finding `:)`

Comment: The buffer sizing has MAXDIGIT set sufficient to hold  21-chars extra characters (20 with `'\0'`) beyond the largest `int` and 12 (11) beyond the largest long before the separator length is used as a multiple. So longest `int` takes `12` chars with null, now take 3-char SEP (length) and `MAXDIGIT * 3  == 96` more than sufficient for the `3 * 9` (max) separators and the largest `int` -- it was sized with excess storage -- which could be tailored a bit closer. I'll have to think on the best narrowing, but I was toying between `div_t` and `ldiv_t` and passing a `long` -- so I sized to handle both

Comment: Also, good catch on the anonymous struct -- I don't know where I was reading and thinking that, but whatever it was (wasn't' the man page -- just checked) I had it in my mind that `div_t`, `ldiv_t` etc.. were typedef'ed anonymous structs -- likely got my wires crossed -- will revisit tomorrow after some sleep.

Comment: Re: `MAXDIGIT` --> I inferred `MAXDIGIT` is the maximum number of _decimal_ digits in an `int` and code's 32 is illustrative of some very wide `int`.  Or was `MAXDIGIT` meant as the _binary_ digits in an `int` - which seems odd given the decimal nature of the task.

Comment: `MAXC` or `MAXCHAR` would have been more descriptive in hindsight...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#define MAX 100

void printIndiviualDigits(int number)  
{  
    int arr[MAX];  
    int i = 0;  
    int j, r,sum=0;

// Till number becomes 0
while (number != 0) {

    // Extract the last digit of number
    r = number % 10;

    // Put the digit in arr[]
    arr[i] = r;
    i++;

    // Update number to number/10 to extract
    // next last digit
    number = number/ 10;
}

// Print the digit of number by traversing
// arr[] reverse
for (j = i - 1; j > -1; j--) {
    printf("%d", arr[j]);
    sum += arr[j];
    if(j > 0){
      printf("+");
    }
}

   printf("=%d",sum);
}
```

// main function

```
int main()  
{  
    int number;
    printf("Enter any number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printIndiviualDigits(number);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without recursion or strings...

Works on the same principle as a base2 bitmask, but works in base10.
Can be made to work for 0 or negative numbers, too (but this is just an exercise, right?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( void ) {

    int values[] = { 1, 35, 654, 2048, 10000, 65365, 1234567889 };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof values/sizeof values[0]; i++ ) {
        int val = values[i];
        int b10mask = (int)pow( 10, (int)log10( val ) );

        printf( "value(%d): ", val );
        char *pref = "";
        int sum = 0;
        // EDIT: Missed testing when rightmost digits '0'
        // while( val ) { // insufficient
        while( val || b10mask ) { // better.
            int dgt = b10mask ? val/b10mask : val;
            sum += dgt;

            printf( "%s%d", pref, dgt );
            pref = " + ";
            val -= dgt * b10mask;
            b10mask /= 10;
        }
        printf( " = %d\n", sum );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value(1): 1 = 1
value(35): 3 + 5 = 8
value(654): 6 + 5 + 4 = 15
value(2048): 2 + 0 + 4 + 8 = 14
value(10000): 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 1  ## New and working after edit.
value(65365): 6 + 5 + 3 + 6 + 5 = 25
value(1234567889): 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 8 + 9 = 53
```

Comment: With 0, output is `value(0):  = 0` rather than expected `value(0): 0 = 0`.  Infinite loop when `val < 0`, but then OP was not so clear on negative values.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I stated in the description "can be made to work for 0 or negative numbers"... Zero is easy... Just print "0 = 0"... Just change the sign of negatives... Why the fuss???

Comment: Not a fuss, just reviewing the code for edge cases. Code speaks louder than the description and so was easy to miss limitations documented in non-code.  An `assert(val > 0);` would clearly show code's limit.  The `(int)log10( val )` idea is intriguing, yet fails for wider integer types like `long long` due to rounding.  The "Just change the sign of negatives" idea is often an issue with `INT_MIN`.

Comment: This is a "Sunday afternoon at the park" problem, not a "Fly astronauts to Mars" problem... All good... :-)